# Is this exponential family Gaussian?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $m$ be a positive measure on the real line. Assume that $\exp k(t)=\int\exp(xt)m(dx)<\infty$ for $a<t<b$ and that $\exp k(t)=\infty$ if $t\notin[a,b],$, with $-\infty\leq a<b\leq \infty.$ Then $P_t(dx)=\exp (xt-k(t))m(dx)$ is a probability for $t\in (a,b)$ such that $k'(t)=\int xP_t(dx).$ Assume that $m$ has no atoms and that for all $t\in (a,b)$
$$\frac{1}{2}=P_t((-\infty,k'(t)).$$ Is it true that $P_t$ is Gaussian?